# Use multiple password files for nginx

Tags: nginx

I have multiple `server` blocks in my config, all of them using the same file as `auth_basic_user_file`. Now we started to work with some external workforce, and we’d like to add some extra users to one of the `server` blocks, while keeping the original ones, too. Although the documentation doesn’t state it, using multiple `auth_basic_user_file` is not allowed.

Is there a way to do this, without manually merging the password files together? I’m using nginx 1.11.5

Answer (score 3):

yes, this is possible. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html

1. Create a separate password file for the server that should have multiple users. Within the `server` block that should have multiple auth users set `auth_basic_user_file` path to this new password file.
2. Insert the original and the additional user info in new password file like this:

   ```
   name1:password1
   name2:password2
   ```
3. Don't forget to test and reload nginx config:

   ```
   nginx -t
   service nginx reload
   ```

Comment: So you suggest to copy the old password file and add the extra accounts to it? Because that’s exactly what I want to avoid, as if a new intern or employee arrives I have to add their accounts to two files.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your requirements. I thougt the hint you needed was that password files can handle more than one user. Other options that might better fit your needs could be: a) Build nginx with Auth Digest module. b) Create user and group text files and a script to combine them to single password files for each server after a user change. More info for both options see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074766/nginx-group-http-auth)